# SQLAlchemy joining issue (continuous joining)

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy

Didn't quite know how to explain it in the title, but here is what I'm facing.

I need to write, what I thought was a relatively straight forward query (well in SQL anyway):

```
SELECT 
    tasks.*, 
    resource_contact.*, 
    client_contact.* 
FROM 
    tasks, 
    TaskResReln,
    contact resource_contact,
    TaskContact
    contact client_contact,
WHERE
    tasks.task_id = TaskResReln.task_id
    AND TaskResReln.contact_code = resource_contact.contact_code
    AND tasks.task_id = TaskContact.task_id
    AND TaskContact.contact_code = client_contact.contact_code
```

Not much of a query there in my eyes; very straight forward... However, turning this into an SQL Alchemy query is doing my

```
tasks = db.session.query(Tasks,client_contact,resource_contact)\
    .join(TaskResReln, resource_contact)\
    .reset_joinpoint()\
    .join(TaskContact, client_contact)
```

My thinking here was (and from trying to make sense of the manual). That because "Tasks" is the first model in the query() it should be the reset point no? So I thought, first join up the resource side, reset the join, then join up the client side... Wrong.

It generates this SQL:

```
FROM 
    tasks JOIN task_res_reln ON tasks.task_id = task_res_reln.task_id 
    JOIN contact AS contact_2 ON contact_2.contact_code = task_res_reln.contact_code 
    JOIN task_contact ON contact_2.contact_code = task_contact.contact_code 
    JOIN contact AS contact_1 ON contact_1.contact_code = task_contact.contact_code
```

As you can see; the first part is doing swimmingly until it hits task_contact... Then it all goes south from there.

How would I be able to achieve my query? Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get an impression from the docs that `reset_joinpoint()` is meant to be used with automatic aliasing of `join()` (when `aliased=True` flag is passed to it). In your case you can provide `ON` clause yourself:

```py
q = session.query(Tasks, client_contact, resource_contact).\
    join(TaskResReln).\
    join(resource_contact).\
    join(TaskContact, Tasks.task_id == TaskContact.task_id).\
    join(client_contact)
```

Comment: I could kiss you Audrius! I was going mental over this one.